# espresso reports ambiguous matcher because of synchronization issue

Tags: android, android-espresso

My code has no threading or coroutines or async anything. It is just an adapter for RecyclerView that implements kotlin's stdlib MutableCollection interface. My test is failing, but visually seems to be working (and I saw it pass once, so I think this is a race issue).

here is my test

```kotlin
@get:Rule
val activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

@Test
fun AddTwoItemsThenRemoveOne() {
  activityRule.scenario.onActivity {
    it.list.add(1)
    it.list.add(12345)
  }
  val x = 1 - 1 //This line just for breakpoint
  activityRule.scenario.onActivity { it.list.remove(1) }
  val y = 1 + 1 //This line just for breakpoint
  onView(withId(R.id.item_text_id)).check(matches(withText("12345")))
}
```

Here is what a screenshot looks like at a break point on val x = 1-1
[image]

Looks go so far.
Then I remove the first element. Here is a screenshot at val y = 1+1
[image]
So everything looks like it works great, but the test fails

```
androidx.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException:...

+-------->MaterialTextView{id=2131230949, res-name=item_text_id, visibility=VISIBLE, width=140, height=66, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@a38a9b5, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=12345, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} ****MATCHES****
|

+-------->MaterialTextView{id=2131230949, res-name=item_text_id, visibility=VISIBLE, width=28, height=66, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@9ba93bb, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=1, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} ****MATCHES****
```

Really seems like my code works. I am guessing the test is failing because actions on the activityRule happen in a non-blocking way which lets the assertion fire before the list is finished removing the element.
I've been reading the espresso docs and so far can't find... what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I used an idlingReasource with the recyclerview listener.

```kotlin
@Test
fun AddTwoItemsThenRemoveOne() {
  val count = CountingIdlingResource("UI")
  IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(count)
  activityRule.scenario.onActivity {
    it.list.add(1)
    it.list.add(12345)
    count.increment()
    val rec: RecyclerView = it.findViewById(R.id.rec_view_id)
    rec.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(
        object : RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener {
          override fun onChildViewAttachedToWindow(view: View) {}

          override fun onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View) {
            count.decrement()
          }
        })
  }
  activityRule.scenario.onActivity { it.list.remove(1) }
  onView(withId(R.id.item_text_id)).check(matches(withText("12345")))
}
```